# Make box responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I built two blocks.
The first block ("Our best offers") is not responsive on my mobile device and the second block ("Our recommedations") is responsive. The first block spans the whole row on all devices (!). The HTML code for both blocks is correct as it fits with the rest of my layout perfectly, and I need a container and row for the first block. But how to get the first block responsive because I think it should be already the way I coded it (?)?

Fiddle ... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/hb7ys33b/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="well">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="add_box">
                        <h1 class="add_heading">Our best offers</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="well recommend">
                <div class="add_box">
                    <h1 class="add_heading">Our recommendations</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.well {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    background-color:#6478E8;
    text-align:left;
    border-style:solid;
    border-radius:0;
    border-width:0 
}
```

Comment: both boxes are responsive for me?

Comment: Inside container take two row and take col-sm-12 to each.

Comment: @blairmeister - when you look at both boxes on small device you see they look different, the first spans the whole row, and the second has margins left and right.

Comment: don't look like bootstrap is loaded..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the problem you mention in the Fiddle you provide (I can't even see Bootstrap's CSS for that matter, so I guess your Fiddle is not really complete), however you should keep in mind that according to Bootstrap's model all `columns` should be nested inside a `row`, which should in turn be nested inside a `container` (or `container-fluid` if you want it to take up all the screen's width). See the Bootstrap documentation for [containers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container), as well as the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

This means that your second HTML block should be updated to:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well recommend">
                <div class="add_box">
                    <h1 class="add_heading">Our recommendations</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can of course use the same container for both your wells, ending up with something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="add_box">
                <h1 class="add_heading">Our best offers</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well recommend">
                <div class="add_box">
                    <h1 class="add_heading">Our recommendations</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will notice that in my example I have updated `col-sm-12` to `col-xs-12`. This is because Bootsrap's logic is to define the column styles for the smaller viewport (xs) and then override them for larger viewports if required. Using `col-sm-12` you do get the result you expect, since by default your div will take up the full width available to it, however you have left your column size undefined for extra small viewports, which is a bit inconsistent.

Do also note that Bootstrap also has its own `well` CSS class so I would suggest to either use Bootstrap's `well` or to rename your custom class in order to avoid clashing with Bootstrap's CSS and coming across new problems in the future.

Comment: if any change on the column than only need multiple class for columns here no need for col-sm-12 to col-xs-12 instead put col-sm-12 only it will work in a same way

Comment: I agree you don't need multiple column classes if you don't need to change the columns the `div` uses in different viewports. What I'm saying is that it's better to use `col-xs-12` instead of `col-sm-12`, not that you should use both.

Answer (score 0):

put your second box within a row and container as well. for example.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="well recommend">
            <div class="add_box">
                <h1 class="add_heading">Our recommendations</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: No need another container here, you can take N' number of row inside container

Comment: the problem with that is his container is inside well and if I put another row in container, he won't have the white space between boxes.